# NFC API for Android NDK

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, nfc

I'm working on a multi-platform project that need support for NFC. The project is written in C++ so it would be nice to have access to C++ Android NFC API.

Is there a way to interact with the NFC using the NDK ?

I know that from NDK is possible to call SDK Java methods. In this case i could create a Java class to handle the NFC interaction and then call those methods from C++.

Do you think is possible to develop such mechanism ?

Comment: Have you looked at the libnfc libraries ? One of the problems here is that depending on the device you might have to deal with either libnfc-nxp or libnfc-nci (the latter being the way forward, and be the most used in the majority of devices, which is not true today).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JNI to do it.

Create a Java class that will access Android NFC API and provide you the data in a format that suits your needs. Then access its methods from your C++ code via JNI calls.

Comment: can you provide me any links. how to do that? that will be really helpful.